# Extract data by identifying the pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are receiving the job run data in below format.

[image: Source data]

Requirement is to extract the data for each job start time /end time in below format.

[image: Expected Result]

I want the best way in terms of performance to achieve the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select row_number() over (order by timestampsession) as rownumber,
       scriptno, timestampsession as start_time, end_time
from( select t.*, 
             min(case when scriptname = 'scriptrunner_end' then timestampsession end) over (partition by scriptno order by timestampsession desc) as end_time
      from table t
    ) t
where scriptname = 'scriptrunner_start';
```